# GreenSock and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, gsap

I am writing a program in TypeScript and compiling code to JavaScript before running it on a browser. This is my `package.json` scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rm -rf dist/",
  // gsap.min.js is under ts/src/lib/
  "build": "tsc && copyfiles -u 1 ts/src/lib/* dist/"
},
```

However, I cannot reference `gsap` in a TypeScript file as I get the the error `Cannot find name 'gsap'.` I believe this is because `tsc` does not read minified files (even if `allowJs` flag is true).

I can, however, use `gsap` fine in a JavaScript file, since the checking is less strict. (In JavaScript, referencing a variable that is not defined only throws an error when run, e.g. in browser console.)

### Attempt to fix

I tried defining `gsap`, hoping `gsap.min.js` will then override the variable. However, `gsap` remains `undefined` at runtime (at least `tsc` compiles this with no errors). So this does not work.

```html
<!-- index.html snippet -->
<script src="dist/src/lib/pseudo.js"></script>
<script src="dist/src/lib/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// pseudo.js
let gsap: any;
```

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file? Does `gsap` have a `d.ts` file?

Comment: I have included my `tsconfig` in my post now. The only file related to `gsap` is `gsap.min.js` in my repository.

Comment: If you *install* gsap (`npm install gsap`) rather than just copying a minified version of it into your project, it should resolve the problem has `gsap` provides type definitions (https://github.com/greensock/GSAP/tree/master/types). That assumes you're using a bundler, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** you use a bundler, then if you *install* gsap (`npm install gsap`) rather than just copying a minified version of it into your project, it should resolve the problem has `gsap` provides type definitions.

If you're not using a bundler, copy the `.d.ts` files containing the types (from https://github.com/greensock/GSAP/tree/master/types) into your project's directory tree, and if TypeScript doesn't automatically pick them up, point it at them via `tsconfig.json`. The type files include the necessary declaration to tell TypeScript about the `gsap` global (specifically, that declaration is in `gsap-core.d.ts`).